# ActiveRecord keeping scope encapsulated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope, arel

I have two models, `foo` and `bar`, `foo` has many `bars`.

`Bar` is an event that happens for a given period of time, so I'd like a method or scope that returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` representing the foos that have currently active bars.

This is easy enough in the `Foo` class with a scope:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :bars

scope :has_current_bars, joins(:bars).where('bar.foo_id IS NOT NULL').where('bar.starts_at <= ?', DateTime.now).where('bar.ends_at >= ?', DateTime.now)
```

What I don't like about this, is that `foo` needs to know an awful lot about the internals of `bar`.

Can this be rewritten, possibly by adding a scope on `bar`, so `foo` doesn't need to know about `bar` attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. You can, and should, move the scope to `Bar`.

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo

  scope :current, where('starts_at <= ? AND ends_at >= ?', DateTime.now, DateTime.now)
end

foo = Foo.first
foo.bars.current # Will return all of foo's bars which match the scope

# EDIT:
bars.current.map(&:foo) # Will return all foos that have current bars
```

Comment: Actually, I think you might have them mixed up.

Comment: This is a little different from what I have.  Mine returns the foos that have current bars.  Yours, as you mention, returns current bars, given a foo

Comment: @SooDesuNe See my edit for how you can get all foos with current bars.

Comment: @vonconrad, thanks for you attention.  We are getting in the right direction, unfortunately bars.current.map(&:foo) returns an array, not an ActiveRecord::Relation, so all chaining is dead after this.

Comment: @SooDesuNe What is it you need to do with the foos after fetching the ones with current bars? In other words, why do you need it to be a an ActiveRecord::Relation?

Comment: I don't have a need right now, but I like to keep query results as ActiveRecord::Relation for as long as possible incase of future chaining needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars

  def self.has_current_bars
    joins(:bars).merge(Bar.current)
  end

  # or
  scope :has_current_bars, joins(:bars).merge(Bar.current)
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :current, where('bar.starts_at <= ?', DateTime.now).where('bar.ends_at >= ?', DateTime.now)
end

foos = Foo.has_current_bars
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encapsulate your query objects, I have written a micro library that makes it really simple to move complex query logic outside of your models and controllers.

https://github.com/ElMassimo/queryable

It takes care of making your scopes chainable, and delegating methods like each and map to the actual query.

For this case, you could have two query objects, FooQuery and BarQuery, and make this objects collaborate so that each query object takes care of encapsulating the logic related to its corresponding model.